# Discrete math Union and Intersections

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My professor gave us some problems and their answers.

The problem I'm asking a question about is this:

$$R_{1}=\{((1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$$
and
$$R_{2}=\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)\}$$

a)$R_{1}\cup R_{2}$.

b)$R_{1}\cap R_{2}$.

---

The answer says:

a)$R_{1}\cup R_{2} = \{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$.

b)$R_{1}\cap R_{2} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)\}$

Shouldn't it be the other way around? 
Shouldn't the union be all the elements from both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$, and the intersect just the elements that are in both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$.

I don't know if it's a mistake or not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Stefan Kostoski, welcome to math stackexchange. On this board you are expected to use mathjax to write your questions, so your question may attract some downvotes. You can read more on mathjax here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: With regards to your question. You are right the answers should be the other way around. I suspect your professor made a typo, proving that mathematicians are humans after all. :-)

Comment: Sorry about the mathjax, I didn't know that existed, but I'll use it next time. Thank you for the quick reply. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Floris Claassens said, the professor made a typo and the union should be all the elements from both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ and the intersect should be just the elements that are included in both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$.